# epsilon delta of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Hey can anybody help me with the following proof? I am trying to solve the following limit using epsilon delta and I have found the limit to be 1/3 using the squeeze theorem and have got to this thus far but am a bit confused where I go now as I have both a 3x and a sinx when trying to find an epsilon??
Thanks in advance!![image]

Answer (score 2):

You can easily show that $$\frac{\sin(x)+1}{3x+1}<\frac{2}{3x}$$
and then it is easy to show that $$\frac{2}{3x} < \epsilon $$

Comment: Ahhh! I must've been blind!! How did I miss that!! Thankyou :) so x>2/3e and then I can set delta =max(0, 2/3e) and sub it back in to give epsilon greater than my original equation and the proof is done??

Comment: you seem to have understood

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong definition of limits for this case. When dealing with limits at infinity, you want to use [this](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/math-proof/limits-at-infinity/limits-at-infinity.html) definition. As RowanS stated, you can use the fact that the absolute value of sin(x) is bounded in the proof.

Comment: that would explain a lot!! Thanks for picking up on that :)